# Refactor JS/jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Premise:

I am creating a page that contains many HTML options with relations like `Product-> SubProduct-> Task`. `Task` depends on `SubProduct` which in-turn depends on `Product` to Load.

I am repeating my code multiple times in my javascript.

### Problem:

I have repeatedly tried to change this code, but I have a multitude of variables. I tried creating a function, but in vain since I am using `$each`

I accept any suggestions to refactor this code in any capacity.

### Code:

```js
$("#ProductId").change(function () {
    $("#SubProductId").empty();
    $("#TaskId").empty();
    $("#SubProductId").append('<option value="0">[Select ...]</option>');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlGetSubProducts,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { productId: $("#ProductId").val() },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                $("#SubProductId").append('<option value="'
                 + data.SubProductId + '">'
                 + data.Name + '</option>');
            });
            ValidateFilledFields();
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert('Fail to find subproduct.' + ex);
        }
    })
    return false;
})
        
       
       
    return false;
 })
```

```html
<div>
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ProductId, "Product")
 @Html.DropDownList("ProductId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
</div>
```

### Notes:

`ProductId` is the property id from the HTML above

Comment: Not sure why you have "product" and "version" when you said "city", "state", and "country".

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, I Edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Proposal:

You can easily design your logic to follow a structured approach like so:

```js
const getCountries = _ => new Promise((res,rej) => $.ajax({
    ...yourNormalConfigData,
    success: res,
    fail: rej,
})).then(d => d.countries) // Get contries from response 

const getStates = country => new Promise((res,rej) => $.ajax({
    url: `/foo/bar/get/States?country=${country}`,
    ...yourNormalConfigData,
    success: res,
    fail: rej,
}).then(d => d.states) // Get states from response 

const getCities = state => new Promise((res,rej) => $.ajax({
    url: `/foo/bar/get/Cities?state=${state}`,
    ...yourNormalConfigData,
    success: res,
    fail: rej,
}).then(d => d.cities) // Get cities from response

const injectOptions = elem => arr => {
  const html = arr.map(c => `<option>${c}</option>`).join('')
  elem.html(html)
}

const el = {
  country: $('#Countries'),
  state: $('#States'),
  city: $('#Cities'),
}
getCountries().then(injectOptions(el.country))

el.country.change(e => {
  getStates(el.country.val()).then(injectOptions(el.state))
})

el.state.change(e => {
  getCities(el.state.val()).then(injectOptions(el.city))
})
```

```html
<select id='Countries'>
</select>
<select id='States'>
</select>
<select id='Cities'>
</select>
```

### Notes:

This is leveraging `promises`, and a ton of *code re-use* so that you can use the same components to load and configure your data dynamically. I tried not to deviate significantly from your code-base. It also features curried functions for a neater promise logic flow!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to improve that you can make to your code as you have it, is to use string interpolation

```
               $("#VersionId").append(`<option value="
                 ${data.VersionId}">
                ${data.VersionName}</option>`);
```

Note: that is omitting the county->state -> city paragraph since is not related with the ajax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals